FME- problems transforming GML to IFC
I created a very simple model where I added a GML reader and I want to transform it to IFC.
When I run it, numbers appeared on the connectors. These numbers match with the number of features per feature type. I would assume that the transformation was made, although a couple of warnings appeared during the run of the model (see second image)


Nevertheless, when I look for the transformed files, there is nothing on the folder. When I try to inspect the resulting data using the eye, a windows pops up asking for information that was set when i first set the "writers/translator" (see third image) and when I look for the data, nothing was done.

I checked about these “warnings” among the FME community, and between not-updated information and broken links, there was nothing there that could help me to find out the reason or meaning or ground for this issue.
I have also checked in https://support.safe.com/hc/en-us/articles/25407793929229-GML-Writing  and here https://support.safe.com/hc/en-us/articles/25407506592653-GML-Reading but unfortunately I cannot solve my problem
I am using the version FME(R) 2024.0.1.0, I am using windows 8 64 bit.
I will appreciate any hint that could help me to solve this matter
Thanks
